# VSCode keyboard shortcut for 'Assign expression result to new local variable'?

Tags: typescript, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In Eclipse, there's this really handy shortcut, mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> by default, which works when an expression is selected. What it does is to create a new local variable to hold the result of the expression. For example...

`this.doSomeCalculation();`

If the mouse cursor is positioned over the line above, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will turn the line into...

`double someCalculation = this.doSomeCalculation()`

I find myself using this shortcut a lot when coding Java. Is there something similar available for editing Typescript in **Visual Studio Code**?

Answer (score 5):

Almost similar thing on vscode on this link

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing

It shows how to extract a part of code to local variable. 
It's a little diferent from eclipse. On vscode it needs to "select" the statement and then press ctrl + shift + R then pops a window where you need to select to extract to local variable.

You could configure Keyboard Shortcut to Ctr + 2 l.

Really it is not same thing but...

Answer (score 5):

You can [assign keybinding to refactorings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_keybindings-for-code-actions) such as extract constant.

Here's a keybinding that binds <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to the extract constant refactoring:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
  "command": "editor.action.refactor",
  "args": {
    "kind": "refactor.extract.constant",
    "apply": "first"
  }
}
```

This keybinding will work in JavaScript and TypeScript (and in any other languages that have an extract constant refactoring)

P.S. Here is a slight variation for JS/TS that lets a single keybinding work for both extract type and extract constant:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
  "command": "editor.action.refactor",
  "args": {
    "kind": "refactor.extract",
    "preferred": true,
    "apply": "first"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get this working through a bit of trial and error in `keybindings.json`. For you I think the mapping will look something like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+2 ctrl+l",
    "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
    "args": {
      "kind": "refactor.assign.variable"
    },
    "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
]
```

I'm personally using `ctrl` + `alt` + `space`:

```
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+space",
    "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
    "args": {
      "kind": "refactor.assign.variable"
    },
    "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select an expression and then:

In Mac:

<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

In Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Not working for windows...

Comment: @Kıvılcım Go to the small wheel in the vscode at the bottom left -> Keyboard Shortcuts, after that type: editor.action.codeAction and check which keybindig is bound with this command.

Comment: the suffix codeAction does not exist under editor.action.* , or anywhere else. By the way, I am using version 1.61.2